# Configuring Couchbase Server and Couchbase Sync Gateway

Tags: node.js, couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway

I am successfully connecting my couchbase server with my application using localhost:3000

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var couchbase =require("couchbase");
var request = require("request");

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));


var cluster = new couchbase.Cluster('couchbase://localhost'); 
cluster.authenticate('Administrator', 'ABcd1234'); 
var bucket = cluster.openBucket('non-med'); //the name of bucket is 'example'
bucket.on('error', function(err) { console.log('Bucket: CONNECT ERROR:', err);}); 

module.exports.bucket = bucket;

var routes = require("./routes.js")(app);

var server = app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Listening on  port%s...", server.address().port); 
});
```

I have also downloaded Couchbase Sync Gateway from on my mac in commend line and service is loaded shown as follows

```
sudo ./sync_gateway_service_install.sh
chown: sync_gateway: illegal user name
chown: sync_gateway: illegal user name
/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.couchbase.mobile.sync_gateway.plist: service already loaded
```

Could everyone tell you how can i configure the Conuchbase Sync Gateway in detail??

- Any amendment on the app.js
- Is there any new file needed to create e.g. sync-gateway-config.json?
  If so,
- (2a)Where do i include this file? My application project folder?
- (2b)May i know the format of json?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sync gateway needs to run as a separate file.You can set set syncing criteria by creating channels in `http://localhost:4985/_admin/`. You can refer https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/installation/sync-gateway/index.html to run the sync-gateway. I'll attach a sample sync-gateway configuration file below. Cheers!!

```
{
    "log": [
        "HTTP+"
    ],
    "adminInterface": "localhost:4985",     //Public port
    "interface": "localhost:4984",       //Admin port
    "databases": {
        "your_cluster_name": {          //add your couchbase cluster name
            "server": "http://localhost:8091",  //add couchbase server url
            "username": "your_username",
            "password": "your_password",
            "bucket": "your_bucket_name",
            "users": {
                "GUEST": {
                    "disabled": true
                },
                "admin": {
                    "admin_channels": ["*"],  //give permission to all the channels
                    "password": "123456"   //admin channel password
                }
            },
            "import_docs": "continuous",
            "enable_shared_bucket_access": true,
            "sync":`
           function(doc) {
                channel(filter); // set your filtering criteria          
            }`
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sync Gateway talks directly to Couchbase Server.  (In production you will usually not run them on the same machine.  Make sure firewall/network filtering doesn't block access.)

Sync Gateway listens for connections from your client (mobile) applications.  It does not interact with your Node app in most typical scenarios.

You configure Sync Gateway by supplying a file with your parameters.  The name of the file is not important.  The format and parameters are in the documentation here: https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/guides/sync-gateway/config-properties/index.html

There are also sample configuration files included in the Sync Gateway distribution.

You do not need to create channels via the admin interface.  You typically do this in the configuration file or via the sync function.  It is very important to understand the sync function and what it does.  See the documentation here: https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/2.0/guides/sync-gateway/sync-function-api-guide/index.html